# Link relative to Application root with client tag

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to link to the application root with the ~ character (or something similar) in a client tag (e.g. <link>)? I have some external stylesheets and scripts that I need to link to in a Master page, but I don't want to hardcode the path relative to the IIS site, I want to do it based on the relative application path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use `<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/meep/moop.css") %>" />`.

Not the prettiest of solutions, but you should only use it a couple of times during development...

Comment: I tried this, but it gets the actual directory path (e.g. "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\" etc.) not the web path.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than invoke ResolveUrl method, you could simply include the tilde and the runat attribute as follows:

> <a href="~/page.aspx" runat="server">My Link</a>

This will resolve from the root always.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It appears that this works for anchor tags, but not for link tags.